# When minting there is a third box appearing called 'signature (bytes)' what do I enter here?

Tags: transactions, mint

I just looked at a minting contract and in addition to the usual mint price and quantity, there is a third box "signature (bytes)".  I have not seen this before.  What am I supposed to put there?

Answer (score 0):

Its the function you are calling in that contract. The function name is `signature` and the input parameter is `bytes`. If you can share the contract code, it can be explained better.

Comment: I have provided a screenshot : https://imgur.com/R5nOogm
This looks like a parameter to me. Do you imply we need to enter the bytes keccak of the function called by that mint function?